# Collection from Entity not updating after change on database

Tags: jpa

I'm using JPA entities from database, and trying to create, modify or delete registers in database through EntityManager.

I have a 'Company' entity, and this entity has a Collection of 'Employee' entity.

When I modify, create or remove some register in the Employee table, the Collection of 'Employee' from the Company entity is not updated, only when I stop and run the project again (I'm using glassFish server)

However, if I print the whole list of employees directly using the findAll() method using the Employee entity facade, the employees are shown updated.

Here is the code:

```
public class test extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */

    @EJB
    CompanyFacade companyDB;

    @EJB 
    EmployeeFacade employeeDB;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */            
            Company company = companyDB.find("Z-5849729");
            //CREATE
            if(request.getParameter("create")!=null){
                Employee employee = new Employee(3);
                employee.setBirthdate("05/06/1998");
                employee.setCompanyrfc(company);
                employee.setSalary(1600);
                employee.setSector("Client Support");
                employee.setName("Alfonso Guerrero");
                employeeDB.create(employee);
            }


            //REMOVE
            if(request.getParameter("remove")!=null){
                Employee employee = employeeDB.find(3);
                employeeDB.remove(employee);
            }

            //EDIT
            if (request.getParameter("edit")!=null){
                Employee employee = employeeDB.find(3);
                employee.setName("Alfonso Modified");
                employeeDB.edit(employee);
            }

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet test</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println(company.getCompanyrfc()+" |" + company.getName());
            Address address =  company.getZipcode();
            List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>) company.getEmployeeCollection();
            for (Employee employee : employees){
                System.out.println(employee.getName());
                out.println(employee.getName());
            }
            List<Items> items = ( List<Items>) company.getItemsCollection();
            for (Items item : items){
                out.println(item.getItemname());
            }

            List<Employee> employeeList = employeeDB.findAll();
            for (Employee employee : employeeList){
                out.println("<p>"+employee.getName()+"</p>");
            }

            out.println(" |" + address.getCountry() + " " + address.getAdminname());
            out.println("<h1>Servlet test at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }


}
```

When I use the company.getEmployeeCollection() from the Company Entity, I get the list of employees not updated.

If I use the employeeDB.findAll() from the Employee Entity Facade, I get the list of employees updated.

Comment: It is probably related to flushing the entitymanager. Call ```entityManager.flush()``` after the above mentioned operations and check.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your EntityManager flush mode type is set to **COMMIT** and not **AUTO**.
When the flush mode type is set to COMMIT, the flush action, that synchronizes the persistence context to the underlying database occurs at transaction commit.

> `public static final FlushModeType COMMIT`
>
> Flushing to occur at transaction commit. The provider may flush at other times, but is not required to.

If you want the synchronization to the underlying database to occure at execution of the query, set the flush mode type to AUTO

> `public static final FlushModeType AUTO`
>
> (Default) Flushing to occur at query execution.

Alternatively you could directly call the `flush()` operation to explicitely require the synchronization with the underlying DB right after your query.

> `flush()`
>
> Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the flush operation to the CompanyFacade. Now after the lines 'employeeDB.create(employee);', employeeDB.edit(employee); and 'employeeDB.remove(employee);'  I'm using 'companyDB.flush()', but it's still not updating. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Strange... Keep looking around the transaction persistence context and see if a call to ```entityManager.refresh(yourEntity)``` (after the flush) could help